# Python 3 - Issue calling class method outside class

Tags: python, function, class, oop, web-scraping

I've searched for a long time for an answer, got a few results but none of those seem to relate to my use case. I still can't seem to understand why I'm failing to find the issue in my code.

I have a fully working scraper that I wanted to re-write using OOP but I'm having issues when calling one class method outside of the class (All within a for loop). Any help would be much appreciated.

***My Code:***

```
class IndeedScraper(object):
    def __init__(self, role, max_pages):
        self.role = role
        self.max_pages = max_pages
        self.url = "https://ie.indeed.com/jobs?as_and={}&radius=25&l=Dublin&fromage=3&limit=50&sort=date".format(role)

    # Finds number of pages resulting from search term provided
     def find_pages(self):

        return pages   # Returns a List of URLs

    # Parses relevant information from each page    
    def find_info(self):

      return l    # Returns a List of Dictionaries with the parsed information

if __name__ == '__main__':

    role = str(input("Enter role to search: "))
    max_pages = int(input('Enter number of pages to scrape: '))

    scraper = IndeedScraper(role, max_pages)

    l_main = []
    pages = scraper.find_pages()

    for i in pages[:max_pages]:
        html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(i)
        source = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html5lib")
        print("Scraping Page number: " + i)
        results = scraper.find_info(source)  # THIS IS WHERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO CALL THE 'find_info' function to make it work
        l_main.extend(results)

    # Put all results into a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(l_main)
    df = df[['Date', 'Company', 'Role', 'URL']]
    df=df.dropna()
    df.sort_values(by=['Date'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
    df.to_csv("csv_files/pandas_data.csv", mode='a', header=True, index=False)
```

***Error Displayed:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class_indeed_TEST.py", line 99, in <module>
    df = df[['Date', 'Company', 'Role', 'URL']]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2133, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2177, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1269, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: "['Date' 'Company' 'Role' 'URL'] not in index"
```

Comment: Is this a [mcve]? Can't you reduce this a bit?

Comment: Reduced the amount of code to make it easier to read and understand.

Comment: I actually got it running fine by adding the imports and adding a parameter to find_info().

Comment: @AshishAcharya If you got it working, post an answer, not an edit.

Comment: @pyrish, can you check if you have those headers in dataframe by checking df.columns?

Comment: @pyrish, what's the role and number of pages you're using?

Comment: I posted everything before but I was told it was too much code. I'm looking for the term 'qa' and number of pages = 2. Thanks Ashish

Comment: @Ashish Acharya, I had the imports in my code before but didn't add them to the question. I also made the changes you sugested but I'm still getting the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the find_pages function. Here's the original find_pages function you posted:

```
# Finds number of pages resulting from search term provided
 def find_pages(self):
    pages = []
    html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
    source = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html5lib")
    base_url = 'https://ie.indeed.com'
    for a in source.find_all('div', class_= 'pagination'):
      for link in a.find_all('a', href=True):
        pages.append(base_url + link['href'])
    pages.insert(0, base_url + '/jobs?q=test&l=Dublin&sort=date&limit=50&radius=25&start=0')
    pages.pop()
    return pages
```

When you're calling the script for role "qa" the site returns all the results on the same [page](https://ie.indeed.com/jobs?as_and=qa&radius=25&l=Dublin&fromage=3&limit=50&sort=date). Therefore, the page doesn't have any divs with `class=pagination`. So, this line returns an empty list:

```
for a in source.find_all('div', class_='pagination'):
```

...which means this is empty as well:

```
    for link in a.find_all('a', href=True):
```

so you're returning an empty list from the `find_pages` function and ultimately pandas is creating an empty dataframe.

To fix this, just add a condition to check whether the pagination div is empty like so:

```
# Finds number of pages resulting from search term provided
def find_pages(self):
    pages = []
    html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
    source = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html5lib")
    base_url = 'https://ie.indeed.com'

    # <edited code>
    pagination_divs = source.find_all('div', class_='pagination')
    if not pagination_divs:
        return [base_url + '/jobs?q={}&l=Dublin&sort=date&limit=50&radius=25&start=0'.format(self.role)]

    for a in pagination_divs:
        for link in a.find_all('a', href=True):
            pages.append(base_url + link['href'])
    # </edited code>

    pages.insert(0, base_url + '/jobs?q=test&l=Dublin&sort=date&limit=50&radius=25&start=0')
    pages.pop()
    return pages
```

Note: You might need to edit the code to do something else when the div doesn't exist based on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @Ashish Acharya. You made me realize I was using a slightly different url to grab the number of pages, that's why the 'pagination' class was not there, hence making the resulting list empty. I have changed the code and now I'm debugging the code to try to include the 'Sponsored' adds which are currently being skipped since they have a different class than the 'Date' field. Cheers